# Representing tensor products using Dirac's bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, notation

I know, that $$ \uparrow \equiv \left[ \begin{array} { l } { 1 } \\ { 0 } \end{array} \right] $$ and $$ \bigg| \frac { X - i Y } { \sqrt { 2 } } \bigg \rangle = \sqrt { \frac { 3 } { 8 \pi } } \frac { x -   iy  } { r } $$ but I don't know $$ \bigg| \frac { X - i Y } { \sqrt { 2 } } \uparrow \bigg\rangle $$ what this function means. Can a matrix represent a function?

Can anyone help me? I don't understand quantum mechanics very well.

Comment: @FangijaZhu I think that you should ask the same question in [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) too.

Comment: The second equation looks wrong - left hand side is some kind of quantum state, right hand side is just a number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there are kets from different spaces put together, it is assumed that there is a hidden tensor product. So

$|\psi\ \rangle\  |\uparrow\ \rangle\ $ actually means $|\psi\rangle \otimes |\uparrow\ \rangle$.

In the same way, notation can put everything inside the same ket. For example:

$$ | n\ \mathcal{l},\ m_l,\ s,\ m_s \rangle $$

is also

$$ | n\ \mathcal{l},\ m_l\rangle \otimes |s,\ m_s \rangle $$

Because the first one is the spatial part, and the second part is the spin. They belong to different spaces. The spatial part is in $\mathcal{H}$, and the spinpart is $\mathbb{C}^n$, usually $\mathbb{C}^2$, which are ½ spins.

Comment: Thanks, self study person, I never noticed this before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is a little bit confusing, and being careful with notations is really important in quantum mechanics. However, I think I may help you. This resultant state

$$\bigg| \frac { X - i Y } { \sqrt { 2 } } \uparrow \bigg\rangle$$

that you get, is probably the tensor product of the the previous ones. This tensor product is a vector that lives in a Hilbert Space which is itself a tensor product of the Hilbert Spaces in which the states $$\uparrow$$ and $$\bigg| \frac { X - i Y } { \sqrt { 2 } } \bigg \rangle$$ lives. You can represent this resultant state as column matrix that will have $$d_{1}d_{2}$$ components, where $$d_{1} ; d_{2}$$ are the dimensions of the Hilbert Spaces that composes the Hilbert Space in which the resultant state lives.